# Embed jQuery after page load with Firebug

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

I want to embed jQuery on a website with Firebug after it finished loading.

I tried putting `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` in the `BODY` tag with Firebug but that didn't work.

With Firebug I cannot access the `HEAD` part of the website where the `<script>` tag actually belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```